# Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous map between topological spaces prove $f$ admits a left inverse

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous map between topological spaces prove

a) if $f$ admits a Continuous left inverse, it is a topological embedding

b) if $f$ admits a continuous right inverse, it is a quotient map

(question 3-13 from Introduction to topological manifolds by John Lee 2nd edition p82 )

My thought is we can define a relation on $X$ by $x\sim y$ if $f(x)=f(y)$ then we have the quotient map $q:X\rightarrow X/\sim $ now by universal property we have a unique continuous map $g:X/\sim Y$ which is an embedding. My problem is this map is not an inverse for $f$ .. I think for the other part I need to look at the disjoint union quotient by a relation related to $f$?

Comment: The statements you are trying to prove are ungrammatical and the most obvious interpretation of them is false.

Comment: *if* $f$ admits a *continuous* left inverse, *then* it is a topological embedding; *if* $f$ admits a *continuous* right inverse, *then* it is a quotient map.

Comment: What is a left inverse it is a map $g$ such that $g(f)$ is the identity on a subset of $X$ right?.

Comment: @EricWofsey you mean the question is wrong ??

Comment: @Magdiragdag how to define a left inverse or a right inverse then? $f$ is not one to one or onto . Or could we look onto the image of $f$ $f:X\rightarrow f(X)$ then $g:f(X)\rightarrow X/\sim$ it is embedding clearly.

Comment: You are still quoting the question wrong (and they're still not even grammatically correct). For 1) you don't have to prove that $f$ admits a left inverse; you assume it has one and then you have to argue that $f$ is an embedding.

Comment: @Magdiragdag okay thanks I see now hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous map, then $f$ is an embedding iff $f$ admits a continuous (left inverse) $g: f[X] \to X$ satisfying $g \circ f = 1_X$.

If $g$ exists then $f$ is 1-1 (standard set theory fact) and $f$ obeys the universal property for $X$ having the initial topology wrt $f$:

> For all spaces $Z$ and all functions $:h: Z \to X$, $h$ is continuous iff $f \circ h: Z \to Y$ is continuous.

To see this property from the existence of $g$ is quite easy: Let $Z$ be a space and $h: Z \to X$ be a function. If $h$ is continuous, so is $f \circ H$ (composition of continuous maps) and if $f \circ h$ is continuous so is

$$g \circ (f \circ h) = (g \circ f) \circ h = 1_X \circ h = h$$

again as a composition of continuous maps.
And a 1-1 mapping with the domain having the initial topology is an embedding.

Or you could say that $g$ witnesses that $f: X \to f[X]$ is a homeomorphism.

The quotient case is similar but using the dual universal property:

> For all spaces $Z$ and all functions $h: Y \to Z$, $h$ is continuous iff $h \circ f: X \to Z$ is continuous.

which is then equivalent to having a continuous right inverse $g: Y \to X$ (a continuous selector, as it picks a representative for each class, as it were) with $f \circ g = 1_Y$.